# Ubuntu alternative downloads US mirror is down

Tags: downloads, alternative

The US mirror for downloading alternative versions of Ubuntu is down, and apparently has been down since February 1st. Is there going to be a solution for that soon? I understand that some of the other mirrors work, but I still think that the US mirror needs to be replaced.